# Cannot convert int string into chr string

Tags: python

I am very new to Python coding and am currently taking courses on Grok Learning.
There is a specific question I am stuck on, I have tried everything I can think of. It is probably obvious as hell but I am completely braindead with this one. Here is my code and error message:

```
values = int(input("Codes: "))

separated_values = values.split()

for value in separated_values:

  print(chr(value))
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program.py", line 1, in <module>
    values = int.split(" ")
AttributeError: type object 'int' has no attribute 'split'
```

[image: The problem i need to fix]

Comment: I guess you mean `values = input("Codes: ")` instead...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are converting the inputted `str` into an `int`. You need to keep it as a `str` in order to split it, so remove the "`int(...)`" from line 1. You need to convert each individual value into an `int` in the `for` loop instead. So:

```
values = input("Codes: ")
separated_values = values.split()
for value in separated_values:
    print(chr(int(value)))
```

Answer (score 0):

**this is what you want:**

```
values = input("Codes: ")

separated_values = values.split()

for value in separated_values:

  print(chr(int(value)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the first 2 lines, try this:

```
values = input("Codes: ")
separated_values = [int(char) for char in values]
```

Comment: you need to spilt the values

Answer (score 0):

split() can only be used for strings. Just convert the items in the list to int after the split using int()

```py
values = input("Codes: ")
separated_values = values.split()

#convert string in list into int    
separated_values = [int(i) for i in separated_values]
    
#loop through list
for value in separated_values:

    print(chr(value))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
values = str(input("Codes: "))

separated_values = values.split()

for value in separated_values:

    print(chr(value))
```

Comment: Why `str(input("Codes: "))`? It's already a string.